# Exchange 2010 find activesync policy applied

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

How to find which activesync policies are applied to an user in Ex2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the user mailbox in the EMC and choose properties, then Mailbox Features, highlight Exchange ActiveSync and choose Properties.

Exchange Powershell:

```
Get-CASMailbox -Identity <mailboxID> | fl name, active*
```

that will provide you "better" info, but if you want just the policy

```
Get-CASMailbox -Identity <mailboxID> | fl name, ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy
```